# Waterline-OrientDB - Bi-Directional Edge

Tags: node.js, sails.js, orientdb, waterline, sails-orientdb

I have two models declared in Sails and I'm using the Waterline-Orientdb adapter and don't know how to connect them via a bi-directional edge

Questions Model

```
var Waterline = require('waterline');

module.exports = Waterline.Collection.extend({

  tableName: 'questionsTable',
  identity: 'questions',
  connection: 'associations',

  attributes: {
    id: { type: 'string', primaryKey: true, columnName: '@rid'},
    question  : { type: 'string'},
    user: { model: "User", required: true },
    answerOptions: {type: 'json'},
    imagefile: {type:'string'},
    answers: {
      collection: 'answer',
      via: 'questions',
      dominant:true
    }
  }

});
```

Answer Model

```
var Waterline = require('waterline');

module.exports = Waterline.Collection.extend({

    tableName: 'answerTable',
    identity: 'answer',
    connection: 'associations',

    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'string',
            primaryKey: true,
            columnName: '@rid'
        },
        Answer: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        questions: {
            collection: 'questions',
            via: 'answer'
        }

    }
});
```

I want to be able to create an edge between the two models. The user creates a question and then users can post a response.

Comment: A question can have many answers but an answer can have only one question, seems you need to change the questions tag in answer to `question { model: 'question' }`

Comment: That is true. But say i wanted to model this as many-to-many and wanted an edge. How would i accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo on your answer model:

```
questions: {
  collection: 'questions',
  via: 'answer'
}
```

should be

```
questions: {
  collection: 'questions',
  via: 'answers'  // answers as that is the attribute name in questions model
}
```

Example to create questions, answers and then link them:

```
var question1;
ontology.collections.questions.create({ question: 'question1' })
  .then(function(question){
    question1 = question;

    return ontology.collections.answer.create([{ answer: 'answer1' }, { answer: 'answer2' }]);
  })
  .then(function(answers){
    question1.answers.add(answers[0]);
    question1.answers.add(answers[1]);

    return question1.save();
  })
```

I've created a running example at [github.com/appscot/waterline-orientdb](https://github.com/appscot/waterline-orientdb/blob/master/example/associations/many-to-many.js).

Regards

**UPDATE:** waterline-orientdb is now named sails-orientdb.